# Is there a away were you can make appBar constant in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, appbar, flutter-appbar

So I'm working on an app. Every time when I have to make a new page I always have to make the same appBar from Scratch.

Is it possible to assign this appBar to a constant and use that constant everywhere I need it.?

OR

Is there another way to just have one appBar for the entire app?

Answer (score 1):

To make your Custom Appbar you need to implement PreferredSizeWidget because the AppBar itself implements it.

```
class MyAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
final String screenTitle;

MyAppBar({@required this.screenTitle});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return AppBar(
    title: Text(screenTitle),
    actions: // Whatever you need
  );
}

@override
Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, write your own:

```
class MyAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget{
  const MyAppBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement preferredSize
  Size get preferredSize => throw UnimplementedError();
}
```

The AppBar Widget hasn't a constant constructor so you can't make it const

Comment: I want to now a way to write the code once and use it everywhere without writing the entire code.

Comment: Write your own AppBar Widget once and use it everywhere :)

Comment: instead of `throw UnimplementedError()` use `Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight)`